# How to create a Promise with two callbacks to wait for?

Tags: angular, typescript, promise

My goal is to make a method for loading an object that returns a promise. When I have a callback I just have to call 'toPromise' that creates the Promise from the callback. But now I want to include the wait for the reconnection to the server before getting the object from the server.

```
public loadIntervention( numFI : number ) : Promise<Intervention>
{
    if ( ! this.Connected )
    {
        // here is the callback that detects reconnection
        jQuery.connection.hub.reconnected( () => { ???? }  );
    }


    return this.proxy.server.getIntervention( numFI ).toPromise();
}
```

How should I implement it?

Comment: You usually can chain promises in the following way: `return promiseA.then(() => { return ... <do async operation, returning promiseB>... })` so the returned promise  from the method will be resolved only when `promiseB` is resolved and `promiseB` will be resolved only when `promiseA` will.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a default, already resolved promise:

```
let reconnectionPromise = Promise.resolve();
```

Then, if you need to perform reconnection, simply assign to `reconnectionPromise` the promise returned by reconnection operation:

```
reconnectionPromise = jQuery.connection.hub.reconnected( () => { ???? }  );
```

Then, in the `return` statement of `loadIntervention` function, chain the two promises together:

```
return reconnectionPromise.then(() => this.proxy.server.getIntervention( numFI ).toPromise());
```

So, in this case, if `this.Connected` is `true`, `reconnectionPromise` is an already resolved promise and the `then` function is called immediately performing `this.proxy.server.getIntervention`. Otherwise, if `this.Connected` is `false`, `reconnectionPromise` will be resolved when the reconnection is done and *then* the `then` function performing `this.proxy.server.getIntervention` is called.

Here the complete example:

```
public loadIntervention( numFI : number ) : Promise<Intervention>
{
    let reconnectionPromise = Promise.resolve(); // Default, already resolved, promise
    if ( ! this.Connected )
    {
        // If you need to perform reconnection, assign to "reconnectionPromise" 
        // the promise returned by "jQuery.connection.hub.reconnected"
        reconnectionPromise = jQuery.connection.hub.reconnected( () => { ???? }  );
    }


    // Always chain the reconnectionPromise then do "getIntervention"
    return reconnectionPromise.then(() => this.proxy.server.getIntervention( numFI ).toPromise());
}
```